# Cannot convert � to readable string with iconv

Tags: linux, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, iconv

I have a large text file with a `iso-8859-1` encoding which I obtain from:

```
file -i file.txt
```

When I cat a file to see the data, there will be a �� instead of a Thai string. At first, I think that I can just use `iconv` in linux to convert the encoding format to other type which I found iso-8859-11 format that can read Thai string and think that it will work. Something like this:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t iso-8859-11 file.txt > output.txt
```

But instead, I got this error:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1169
```

which is the location that has ��. I tried with `//TRANSLIT` but still got an unreadable character.

Are there any way that I can convert this text file to read Thai string? I know that I can just open a file with some text editor and save as a encoding format that I want but I have too many files and each file is nearly a gigabyte size. I think that iconv can helpe me convert every file without manually convert each one.

Ps. I have try open with Python:

```
with open('file.txt','r+', encoding='iso-8859-11') as f:
   print(f.read())
```

which can read Thai character perfectly but I need to convert a large and many files here so iconv is needed.

Comment: Maybe try `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t iso-8859-11//TRANSLIT file.txt > output.txt`. Also see [`iconv(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). Or, maybe the font needs to be enabled in the terminal. Or, maybe switch to UTF-8.

Comment: @jww I have tried, it change to something like `1I!.O?A?a?` as I mentioned. Readable but not in Thai character